# Adding xml-stylesheet declaration to Visual Studio generated XML documentation

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xslt, xml-documentation

Visual Studio creates XML documentation at build-time. I have an xml-stylesheet (xslt) that I would like to apply to it. I would like to add this line to the generated file:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Documentation.xsl"?>
```

Preferably, the xslt declaration would be added at build-time. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You might alter the generated xml file in a post-build command, and add this xslt reference tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a post-build batch script. It uses [fart.exe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fart-it/) to add an xsl stylesheet declaration to my XML. I added it as a post-build step in my Visual Studio project.

```
::Postbuild script.
::Adds xsl stylesheet to XML documentation
::%1 is the project directory string

::Only add a stylesheet if it's not already there
findstr /m "xml-stylesheet" %1Documentation\MCM.XML
if %errorlevel%==1 (
    ::Use "Find and Replace Text" (fart.exe) to add xml-stylesheet declaration
    "%1Documentation/fart.exe" -C -q "%1Documentation\MCM.XML" "<\?xml version=\"1.0\"\?>" "<\?xml version=\"1.0\"\?><\?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"Documentation.xsl\"\?>"
    if %errorlevel%==9009 (
        echo .
    ) else (
        if ERRORLEVEL 1  CMD /C EXIT 0
    )
) else (
    cmd /C EXIT 0
)

exit %errorlevel%
```

Thanks @Yaman for pointing me in the right direction.